# How to simplify javascript code for fullscreen elements?

Tags: javascript

I created buttons that will trigger tables to be seen in fullscreen mode.

Each button refers to the table by ID in Javascript. Even the cancel button has it's own ID.

It works but the code is bulky if I want to add more tables.

At this time I need to copy each var/function and re-name them, this makes the code bulky if I have a lot of tables in one page.

As you can see right now I had to duplicate `cancelFullScreen` and added another `cancelFullScreen2` and I had to do the same for `customFullscreen` and `customFullscreen2`.

Ideally the JS code would remain the same so I don't have to duplicate that each time, and I would just add new tables in HTML.

Is there a way to simplify this JS code so that it works on all tables with a certain class? Each table would have it's own button to expand/close.
`(function () {

```
var cancelFullScreen = document.getElementById("cancel-fullscreen");
if (cancelFullScreen) {
    cancelFullScreen.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
    }, false);
}
var cancelFullScreen2 = document.getElementById("cancel-fullscreen-2");
if (cancelFullScreen2) {
    cancelFullScreen2.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
    }, false);
}



var customFullscreen = document.getElementById("fullscreen-table")
    libraryFullscreen = document.getElementById("expand-fullscreen");

if (customFullscreen && libraryFullscreen) {
    libraryFullscreen.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
        if (customFullscreen.requestFullscreen) {
            customFullscreen.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (customFullscreen.msRequestFullscreen) {
            customFullscreen.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (customFullscreen.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            customFullscreen.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (customFullscreen.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            customFullscreen.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }, false);
}


var customFullscreen2 = document.getElementById("fullscreen-table-2")
    libraryFullscreen2 = document.getElementById("expand-fullscreen-2");

if (customFullscreen2 && libraryFullscreen2) {
    libraryFullscreen2.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
        if (customFullscreen2.requestFullscreen) {
            customFullscreen2.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (customFullscreen2.msRequestFullscreen) {
            customFullscreen2.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (customFullscreen2.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            customFullscreen2.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (customFullscreen2.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            customFullscreen2.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }, false);
}
```

})();`

https://codepen.io/MistaPrime/pen/vYBjjWX

Answer (score 1):

Select multiple elements using `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.getElementsByTagName` or `document.getElementsByName`. Loop through the elements and add your click handler to them. No more duplicate code!

Comment: I did fiddle with that but for some reason couldn't get it to work. Can you try that in codepen?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Noremac/pen/LYPmrWy I did it quick and dirty by adding a specific class to each cancel fullscreen button. You will want to follow Brad's answer as it is more fleshed out

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to simplify this JS code so that it works on all tables with a certain class? Each table would have it's own button to expand/close.

Yes, there are a couple ways to do this.

### Method 1: Add the event handler to every desired element

This is what @Noremac is suggesting.  Something like this:

```
for (el of document.querySelectorAll('[data-action="fullscreen"]')) {
  el.addEventListener('click', requestFullscreen);
}
```

In this example, we loop through every element that matches a particular selector.  I'm using the attribute `data-action="fullscreen"` here, but it could just as easily be a class.  This method is fine for when you have few elements that you're adding the handler to, and all of the elements are on the page at the time you want to add the handler.  I suspect that this applies to your use case the best.

### Method 2: Attach event handler to the parent, filter on target

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (!e.target.matches('[data-action="fullscreen"]')) {
    return;
  }
  requestFullscreen();
});
```

In this example, there is only a single event listener, and we attach it to the parent element of the elements you may want to track.  (`body` is really high up... ideally you use something further in the tree so that this handler doesn't run on every single click anywhere.  I'm using it here as an example.)  When the event handler is called, we filter to ensure that the clicked element actually matches what we want.

This method is useful for when you want to track elements that may not be on the page at the time you add the event listener, or if you have a lot of elements to track.  That is, if you have a ton of elements, it may be more efficient to have a single handler that receives more events, than thousands of handlers that will likely never be called.

### Simple polyfill for fullscreen

You might find something like this simpler:

```
const requestFullscreen = document.documentElement.requestFullscreen ||
  document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen.bind(document) }) ||
  document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen ||
  document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen;
```

By using the `OR` operator, `requestFullscreen` will be set to whatever the first truthy value is.  So, if `document.documentElement.requestFullscreen` is a function, then that's what `requestFullscreen` will be set to.  Otherwise, we'll go onto the next in the list, `webkitRequestFullscreen`, etc.

Comment: I think I understand the codepen that @Noremac did for the exitFullscreen. But if I want to implement your suggestion to open tables in fullscreen, which part of the code indicates that the event click needs to open the table within the click and not open the other tables on the page with the same class? Can you give an example in codepen? (if it's not too much to ask)